# Oracle report problem

Tags: oracle, report

I create a oracle report and I check it and it is working fine but where run it in web I get following error:

REP-1401: 'qr_1refcurds': Fatal PL/SQL error occurred.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Advise what? Debug your code?

Comment: Is there no ORA-xxxxx error after that first error message ?  There is usually one that precises the original cause of the problem.

Comment: The qr_1refcurds function is the default name of a generated PL/SQL query returning a reference to a cursor.  It is usually fleshed out around an SQL query at the heart of the report.  Looks to me like your query does not work in your reporting environment.  Could be a privilege pb. i.e. you have enough privs to run the query in interactive mode but when it runs in PL/SQL privileges from roles are not active.  Just finger in the air, given the info we have... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

REP-1401 occurs when trying to DIVIDE by ZERO (0)